# MySQL: get multiple-keyed rows matching several WHERE conditions (probably simple)

Tags: mysql

I have a table of userdata that includes user ID and category IDs. I want to grab all of the users that are associated with multiple category IDs, eg:

`id | UserID | CategoryID`

`1 | 123456 | 999`

`2 | 123456 | 888`

`3 | 123457 | 999`

`4 | 123458 | 777`

So for example, if I wanted to get all users with a categoryID of 999, I'd get 123456 and 123457. I *need* to get all users with a categoryID of 999 **and** 888, which in this case should only give me user 123456. I can't figure out how to write a query to give me this data.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved this myself:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(CategoryID) AS ids FROM tblWebsiteUserStats
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING ids LIKE '%888%' AND ids LIKE '%999%'
```

This works!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.UserID FROM table_1 AS tbl1 LEFT JOIN table_1 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.UserID = tbl2.UserID WHERE tbl1.CategoryID = 999 AND tbl2.CategoryID = 888
```

do the jpb? (I'm not sure)

Comment: This seems to work, but I could have any number of CategoryIDs, that's the issue (basically I'm allowing admins to select users interested in several different categories), not necessarily 2, so joining the table to itself each time will get messy... thank you though!